# How to layout the button and combobox middle?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, layout-manager

I am new to java swing, I wrote a startup program to formart text, but i am confused with the layout,
the result is below:
[image]

I want the combobox and the button are placed middle of the ctrlPanel, and the combobox should not be stretched

```
 public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7553142908344084288L;

private static String[] formats = new String[] {
    "JSON",
    "XML",
    "YAML"
};

public MainFrame() {
    super("jValidator");
    Panel mainPanel = new Panel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    setContentPane(mainPanel);

    JTextArea fromTextArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);
    JScrollPane fromTextAreaScrollPanel = new JScrollPane(fromTextArea);
    fromTextAreaScrollPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    fromTextAreaScrollPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 5, 15, 5));
    mainPanel.add(fromTextAreaScrollPanel);

    JButton fmtButton = new JButton("Format >>");
    JComboBox jComboBox = new JComboBox(formats);
    jComboBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Text Format"));

    JPanel ctrPanel = new JPanel();
    ctrPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(ctrPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    ctrPanel.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    ctrPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 5));

    ctrPanel.add(jComboBox);
    ctrPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(50, 15)));
    ctrPanel.add(fmtButton);
    mainPanel.add(ctrPanel);

    JTextArea toTextArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);
    JScrollPane toTextAreaScrollPanel = new JScrollPane(toTextArea);
    toTextAreaScrollPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    toTextAreaScrollPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 5, 15, 5));
    mainPanel.add(toTextAreaScrollPanel);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainFrame();
}
 }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).  One typical approach would be to put those components into a panel, and add the panel to a `GridBagLayout` with no constraint.  The panel (and components inside it) will be centered in the container.

Comment: You can use setLayout(null) and place all the individual components using setBounds(x,y,width,height) method whereever you want

Comment: `.setPreferredSize(`  See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)  @Stunner *"You can use setLayout(null)"*  Alternately, you could use a course of action that is not going to create twice as many problems as it solves.  Until you come up with some better advice, please read rather than comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `GridBagLayout` instead of a `BoxLayout`...

```
JPanel ctrPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
ctrPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 5));

gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
ctrPanel.add(jComboBox, gbc);
ctrPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(50, 15)), gbc);
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
ctrPanel.add(fmtButton, gbc);
```

[image]

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: @alex2410 You're output looks better then mine ;) - Good example of how different Look and Feels effect layouts though +1

Comment: thanks very much, but I am still not know why these two components(combobox and button) placed in the middle of the ctrlPanel?

Comment: It's the way that layout manager works.  Not an expert with `BoxLayout`

Comment: Thanks, anyway, another problem is: when I resize the frame, these textarea doesnot stretch with frame size?

Comment: My answer would be to use `GridBagLayout`, allowing the `GridBagConstraints` to use `weightx` and `weighty` equal `1` and `fill` to equal `GridBagConstraints.BOTH`...

Answer (score 3):

For that purposes I recommend you to use another `LayoutManager`, for example `GridBagLayout` change creation of `ctrPanel` like next :

```
JButton fmtButton = new JButton("Format >>");
JComboBox jComboBox = new JComboBox(formats);
jComboBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Text Format"));

JPanel ctrPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx=0;
c.gridy=1;
ctrPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 5));
ctrPanel.add(fmtButton,c);
c.gridy=0;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
ctrPanel.add(jComboBox,c);
mainPanel.add(ctrPanel);
```

And it looks like:

[image]